# Should be simple domain alias ala mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Problem.

I am using mod_rewrite on a Godaddy account, shared, cpanel linux webserver...
I am trying to serve content from domain 1, when domain 2 is requested as an invisible redirect.. aka domain aliasing

domain1 is a wordpress site. I'm trying to get a wordpress /catagory/page to act as the content for domain 2. In fact domain 2 should have only that one page of content available, where we have a form 2 email page set up.

Ideally, Any other get requests should visibly redirect to the actual domain.
Naturally a post request should go to the form on the aliased domain (2)...

Googling relevant search terms results in major information overload. I'm sure the answer is out there, I just can't find the solution to this exact scenario. Meanwhile I suspect Godaddy is caching .htaccess, making it even more difficult to find a working solution in a timely manner.

I've tried several variations, waiting 15 minutes between edits, flushing browser cache etc. I can't seem to find the correct syntax, and/or Godaddy caches .htaccess longer than 15 minutes.

My last attempt

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainalias.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainalias.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.actualdomain.com/subdir/subdir/ [R=301,L]
```

That seems like it should do exactly what I want, but it doesnt. 
It does show the domainalias address in the browser URL bar (GOOD) 
BUT, it displays the home page from http://www.actualdomain.com/ (BAD)

It should display http://www.actualdomain.com/subdir/subdir/    while keeping www.domainalias.com in the adress bar.

What am I missing ?

Comment: _"That seems like it should do exactly what I want, but it doesnt."_ - it rather looks like it doesn't do anything. If it did, you _would_ see `http://www.actualdomain.com/subdir/subdir/` in the browser address bar, because `[R=301,L]` means an _external_ redirect.

Comment: Ok.. thanks for that...  but it doesn't even do that, it's as if the condition is ignored, no redirect takes place, visibly or invisibly...   I was thinking L was to indicate last rule..  ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not entirely sure why my prior attempts did not redirect at all, neither visibly or invisibly..  But after some sleep and more reading, I've got exactly what I needed with the following syntax.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/PathToPageHere [P]
```

Comment: The sleep part did the job here. That is: You used a permanent redirect, which is cached in your browser. Afterwards, your browser does no longer do requests to the server, but instead performs the browser-cached response.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt at helpful input but you didn't read the entire question, like this part...  "I've tried several variations, waiting 15 minutes between edits, flushing browser cache etc. I can't seem to find the correct syntax, "

Usually you can tack on a never before seen query string like "?foo=bar"  & force the browser to ignore cache. Works well on Firefox at least. Chrome may still use cache files regardless, so flushing the cache is really the only way to tell if the change worked when using only Chrome.Don't all web dev folk have access to at least 2 or3 browsers?